# GPS error introduced by tall cliff

Tags: gps, garmin

I need to capture the coordinates of several points along the bottom of a tall vertical cliff. Standing at the bottom of the cliff only the half of the sky facing away from the cliff is visible. Is there a way to estimate the type and size of errors this can introduce and is there a way to account for them?

The cliff height varies between 20 to 100 meters and its orientation varies as well. I am using a simple Garmin GPS. For post processing I use python/QGIS.

Comment: I think your going need more satellite fixes and higher end equipment to give better accuracy. A Dual Frequency GPS (in limited devices) might be help in this case https://support.garmin.com/en-CA/en-us/?faq=9NWiPDU4gM0JWMfdWFol7A

Comment: As Mapperz said, using a dual frequency GPS is the way to go. From my experience, using single frequency receivers with minimal blockages around, such as trees and buildings, the results can still have inaccuracies of greater than 1.5m.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to estimate the erros and account for them.  GPS / GNSS can give almost unlimited errors in poor conditions.

Two suggestions to get better measurements:

Moving away from the cliff and using a LASER rangefinder or (long) tape measure could be a solution.  If you get 20M to 50M away from the cliff you should get lower multipath as well as getting a better view of the sky.  Preferably use a distance / distance offset workflow (i.e. capture two points using GPS, measure the distance from each of those points to the target using rangefinder or tape measure).

If your "Simple Garmin GPS" is an old device, try getting a newer unit.  My experience is that recent consumer-grade devices which receive GPS, GLONASS, Beidou, Galileo perform MUCH better than older GPS-only or GPS+GLONASS devices.  Dual frequency (as suggested by Mapperz) is great if you have all the data capture and post-processing software but it doesn't sound like you have a professional set-up!